# SQL Server 2008r2 <--> best version of MS Access for front end

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, ms-access-2007

I am upsizing my back-end from Access 2003 to SQL Server 2008 R2.  My pilot migration attempt went all right, but it appears the Access 2003 front-end won't play well.  (I can make native links if I convert it to an .adp project, but then I can't modify the front-end; so it's back to .mdb, which uses (slow) ODBC links.)

Apparently I should upgrade my clients to a newer version of Access.  Can anyone help me decide between Access 2007 and 2010?

Web delivery is probably not going to be desired, and the SQL Server 2008 R2 is 32-bit.  I might mention finally that my fear of change is probably bigger than my lust for power ... so all things equal, I'd take the smaller step to 2007.

Comment: ODBC links aren't slow with the native ODBC client. For that matter, there are more intermediate layers with ADO from an ADP than there are with ODBC from an MDB. Or so Microsoft says themselves. Try installing the native ODBC client and using that and see if there are issues. I recently did an upsizing with A2003 front end MDB via ODBC, and the performance is superb.

Comment: @David -- I tried the native ODBC client, it didn't facilitate.  Unfortunately our I.S. isn't run very well and it's impossible for me to find out where solutions may be jammed at that level.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried 2007, briefly and 2010 in more depth. I prefer 2010.

You can try it: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/try/try-office-2010-FX101868838.aspx

I prefer working with 2010 and some of the developments are quite exciting, such data macros (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/access/archive/2009/08/13/access-2010-data-macros-similar-to-triggers.aspx) and the ability to move to internet via sharepoint (http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AU4mH0jPntI).

Comment: Thanks, Remou.  Yeh, it may come down to trying it, of course.  If you can add anything specific about your preference, I would be glad to hear about it.